# Removing white space around tikz number line?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm having this problem with tikz in which I'm trying to create this simple number line but a load of unnecessary white spaces pops up:

```
 \item
As a real-number-line graph:\\
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=none,
            xtick={-3,-2,...,4,5}
        ]
            \addplot[line width=0.4mm, draw=blue][domain=-3:5]{0};
            \addplot[draw=blue, fill=white, mark=*] coordinates {(-3,0)(1,0)(5,0)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\item
Interval Notation:\\
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

How would I remove all this white space? Also, why is there so much white space?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! You need to set the ‘height ‘ and ‘width’ of the axis to the values you like.

Comment: Hi, welcomme , Please give a compileable minimum example starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thank you so much; exactly what I needed.

Comment: You're welcome! (Most likely you have a `\pgfplotset{...,width=...}` and/or `\pgfplotset{...,width=...}` somewhere in your file. If you remove this global option you should also be fine.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I don't, actually. I do have `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}` but I doubt that affects anything..

Comment: `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}` just sets the margin of the document. (The `\pgfplotsset` commands are sometimes hidden in other commands. Anyway, you can always set the width and height as you want (with certain limitations).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tikzpicture` in has default height. You need to reduce it to some small value, but not to small (<16mm) since than you will receive error:

```
Package pgfplots Error: Error: Plot height `42.67912pt' is too small. This ca
nnot be implemented while maintaining constant size for labels. Sorry, label si
zes are only approximate. You will need to adjust your height..
```

See, if the following MWE gives what you like to have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item   As a real-number-line graph:

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
height=20mm, width=90mm,    % <---
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=none,
axis line style=-,          % <---
xtick={-3,-2,...,4,5},
ymin = 0, ymax = 1,         % <---
                ]
\addplot[draw=blue, thick, fill=white, mark=*]  
    coordinates {(-3,0) (1,0) (5,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\item   Interval Notation:
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]